# LINQ for checking whether all members of a list are contained within values from a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have a list of `ProductId`:

```
12345
23456
34567
```

And a list of available quantities of each product in various warehouses, by id:

`Dictionary<ProductId,Dictionary<WarehouseId,quantity>>`

How could I check which warehouses have stock (quantity >= 1 of each) of all the products in the list? Is it possible to do it using LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Join `productIds` list

```cs
.Join(productIds, 
    x => x.Key,
    y => y,
    (x, y) => x)
```

or check `productDict` contains key in `productIds`

```cs
.Where(x => productIds.Contains(x.Key)
```

2. Transform to Warehouses List.
3. Flatten the Warehouses List.
4. `.GroupBy` WarehouseId.
5. Transform grouped Warehouse data with `IsAllProductsAvailable`.
6. Query warehouse(s) with `IsAllProductsAvailable = true`.

```cs
var result = productDict
    .Join(productIds, 
                  x => x.Key,
                  y => y,
                 (x, y) => x)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        Warehouses = x.Value
            .Select(y => new 
            {
                ProductId = x.Key,
                WarehouseId = y.Key,
                Quantity = y.Value
            })
            .ToList()
    })
    .SelectMany(x => x.Warehouses)
    .GroupBy(x => x.WarehouseId)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        WarehouseId = g.Key,
        IsAllProductsAvailable = g.All(x => x.Quantity >= 1),
        Products = g.ToList()
    })
    .Where(x => x.IsAllProductsAvailable)
    .ToList();
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kzRQ9K)

> Output

```
[{
  "WarehouseId": 3,
  "IsAllProductsAvailable": true,
  "Products": [
    {"ProductId":12345,"WarehouseId":3,"Quantity":1}, 
    {"ProductId":23456,"WarehouseId":3,"Quantity":50}, 
    {"ProductId":34567,"WarehouseId":3,"Quantity":20}
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following fields:

```csharp
List<int> productIds;
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> quantityByWarehouseByProductId;
```

You could then:

1. intersect `quantityByWarehouseByProductId` (by the dictionary key) with `productIds`, to keep only the relevant entries in `quantityByWarehouseByProductId`
2. select all the *quantity by warehouse ID* inner dictionary entries associated with each relevant product ID and flatten the collection of those, using `SelectMany()`
3. group the result by the warehouse ID (which is the inner dictionary key)
4. keep only the *quantity by warehouse ID* entries where all the desired products are in stock
5. select the warehouse ID

as follows:

```csharp
IEnumerable<int> warehouseIdsWithAllProductsInStock = quantityByWarehouseByProductId
    .IntersectBy(productIds, qbwForPid => qbwForPid.Key)
    .SelectMany(qbwForPid => qbwForPid.Value)
    .GroupBy(qbw => qbw.Key)
    .Where(qsbw => qsbw.All(qbw => qbw.Value >= 1))
    .Select(qsbw => qsbw.Key);
```

Trying to keep the names somewhat short, I have used the following abbreviations in the example:

- `qbwForPid`: quantity by warehouse for product ID
- `qbw`: quantity by warehouse
- `qsbw`: quantities by warehouse

---

Note: This approach assumes that all existing warehouse IDs are present in a  `KeyValuePair` in the inner dictionaries.

---

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vo5d50).